# Static factory disadvantage over constructor

Tags: java, constructor, static-factory

I am going through Effective Java. The very first item makes a convincing case for static factory methods over constructors.

I didn't get the first disadvantage which is

> The main disadvantage of providing only static factory methods is that
>   classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed.

Why do i need to subclass the class having static factory method since static methods can't be inherited?

Can someone please explain.

Comment: What part of *"...classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed."* isn't clear?

Comment: problem updated..i didn't get the relation between static factory method and 'classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed'

Comment: i don't know why people downvote a question so quickly..let us explain the problem first

Comment: @Jarrord- now can u pls explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have a class called `Person`:

```
class Person {
  public static Person createWithFirstName(String firstName) {
    return new Person(firstName, null, null);
  }
  // etc. - more factory methods

  // private constructor
  private Person(String firstName, String lastName, String nickname) { }

  // useful method
  public String getDisplayName() { }
}
```

It's all good and dandy. But now you also need a class called `Programmer`, and you suddenly realize the programmers are persons too!

But all of a sudden, you can't just

```
class Programmer extends Person { }
```

since `Person` doesn't have any `public` constructors.

Comment: Certainly `protected` constructors are useful.  What unique usefulness is there to having *public* constructors?

Comment: It can be argued that not being able to subclass static factories is actually a good thing. As noted in _Effective Java_: "Arguably this can be a blessing in disguise, as it encourages programmers to use composition instead of inheritance". In this case, you could still define a class Programmer which defers to Person for object creation.

Answer (score 2):

For an instance of the subclass to be created, its constructor must be invoked.

And the first thing a constructor **must** do is to call one of its parent class constructor (the compiler inserts a call to `super()` for you if you don't explicitely add it).

If all the parent class constructors are private, the subclass can't call any of them, making the parent class effectively final, i.e. impossible to subclass.

Comment: i just don't understand how is it(the above explanation) related to static factory method?

Comment: `The main disadvantage of providing only static factory methods is that classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed.` What does it mean ? It means if you only provide `static method` as an instantiate source for your class with all constructors as `private` you can't subclass this class because of the reason explain in @JB Nizet and my answer

Comment: @Prateek- but why do i need to subclass the class having static factory method since static methods can't be inherited

Comment: @Anand Exactly the point the statement is trying to make. If you intend to extend your class you shouldn't only have `static factory methods` with all constructors `private`

Answer (score 1):

Few facts

- In subclass each constructor must call `super(..)` (`..` may be arguments) at start of its constructors which invokes superclass constructor.
- To implement correct Static factory pattern all constructors of class with this pattern must be `private` to prevent instantiating class without using factory method.

So since constructors of base class with factory method must be private, derived class will not be able to call `super(..)` which will not let subclass to compile.

Answer (score 0):

When you `instantiate` a `base` class the first thing that happens is invocation of its `parent` class's constructor. If the `parent class constructor` is private it can't be called from outside the class body hence won't work. Remember while you were reading about `inheritance` there was one point stating that if you want to use `super()` it should be first line in the base class constructor, if you don't explicitly use `super()` in base class compiler automatically puts it there for you. Think what would happen if your `parent class constructor` is `private`, the `super()` call will fail.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your class will not support some inheritance features eg  you can not override any of it's  method , you can not use this as a super type for dynamic dispatch .